# Could you teach me for 2 questions from Trump's words on climate issue (possibly) in the debate(?) with Biden?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Actually I would not like to talk about Trump's words because previously it went into HNQ for nothing but I can't run away from asking because simply I would like to know if I like Trump or not.

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/huffpost/ocasio-cortez-trump-presidential-debate-climate-policy-054111160.html),

There is a head line saying,

> Ocasio-Cortez **Lets Loose On 'Unhinged' Trump Name-Dropping Her At The Debate**

Question 1, What would this line mean. My guess is the republican Ocasio Cortez set her tone free (kind of wildy) on Trump after she was called by Trump at the debate? Am I correct?

Question 2 : Trump said,

> They know nothing about the climate. I mean she’s got a good line of stuff, but she knows nothing about the climate, and they’re all **hopping through hoops** for AOC plus three. Not a real plan. It costs $100 trillion.”

What does this bold phrase mean?

Comment: For the third one, please see "[jump through hoops](https://onelook.com/?w=jump+through+hoops&ls=a&loc=home_ac_jump+thrpu)". Or it might not even mean quite that, it could be ridicule. I am unwilling to discuss the others.

Comment: The headline is badly worded.  Dictionaries define "name-dropping" as mentioning someone's name in order to impress other people.  It's generally when a non-famous person mentions a famous person's name in a way that implies they know the person.  It seems this has nothing to do with what Trump did, which was mention a fellow famous (and slightly less famous) person in order to condemn her and her supporters. ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/name-drop )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocasio-Cortez, whose full name is [**A**lexandria **O**casio-**C**ortez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria_Ocasio-Cortez), is widely known and talked about in the media by her initials AOC. She is not a Republican; she is a Democrat. The headline, written in [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline) grammar, uses phrases figuratively and creatively.

"To let loose" normally means to let out a cry or a scream, produce a sound in an uninhibited way. By extension it also means to discharge a weapon in such a manner. That headline is trying to invoke such imagery with a slightly different meaning.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20loose) gives:

> to produce (something, such as a cry) in a sudden and forceful way
> *The crowd let loose an enormous groan when the pass was intercepted.
>
> She let loose (with) a scream.*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/let-loose):

> to make (a sound or remark) suddenly
> *he let loose a hollow laugh*

> to discharge (rounds) from a gun or guns
> *they let loose a couple of rounds of ammunition*

Thus the headline means AOC criticized (likened to discharge of criticism) Trump name-checking her (Trump's mention of her name) at the last presidential debate.